# Fancybox v3.0.2 plugin for Wordpress on iPhone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, fancybox

I am running Wordpress v3.6.1 and have the Fancybox v3.0.2 plugin installed for displaying gallery images.

On a desktop when I click on one of the images on my Gallery page the image is popped and left/right arrows appear on the popped image enabling me to scroll through the images in the Gallery by clicking on the left or right arrow on the popped image. On the iPhone, however, clicking on the left/right arrows on the popped image has no affect at all.

Would anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks